# Pandas split rows, divide and auto assign date without using explode()

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any smart way to split (explode) a row into multiple rows without using explode, at the same time intelligently divide a column value equally?

Suppose I have a data like this:

```
date quantity  days
5-mar      10     1
8-mar      30     3
9-Mar      10     1
```

and the resultant data ought to be like this:

[image]

I have tried to use assign - but to no avail. Issit that the only way to do it is through iterrows(), loop through it and explicitly create new rows?

P/s: Due to certain restrictions and I have to use pandas <0.25, so I can't really use `.explode()`

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: why do all dates just have values of 10 and 1 in the other columns? and where did the two new dates come from? where did the 30/3 go?
do you just want a df with all dates, and a constant value in the other two columns?

Comment: No, the reason is because the missing two days are weekends, and so the `8 March` has a cumulative of 3 days worth of quantity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for new rows by column `days` and then need some processing for all columns - division for `quantity`, remove days by counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and set `days` to `1`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d-%b')
df1 = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['days'])]


df1['quantity'] = df1['quantity'].div(df1['days'])
df1['date'] -= pd.to_timedelta(df1.groupby(level=0).cumcount(ascending=False), unit='d')
df1['days'] = 1

df1['date'] = df1['date'].dt.strftime('%d-%b')
print (df1)
     date  quantity  days
0  05-Mar      10.0     1
1  06-Mar      10.0     1
1  07-Mar      10.0     1
1  08-Mar      10.0     1
2  09-Mar      10.0     1
```